# Check all checkboxes in listview in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to iterate through all `li` elements and mark them as checked when the `li:first-of-type` is selected.

So far I have been able to select the first `li` and return `true`/`false` when selected. From this I want to check all below checkboxes in the list. Any ideas of help on the matter?

```
elements.each(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();

    if (data.showall == 1) {
        $(this).find("li:first-of-type").find("input").on("change.checkAll", checkAll)
   }
});

function checkAll(e) {
    console.log(e)
    var checked = $(e.srcElement)[0].checked;
    console.log(checked)

    if (checked) {           
        // iterate through all Li's and mark as checked
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML? otherwise all answer will mostly be guess work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code for it provided that all Li are in following manner

```
<li> <input type="checkbox"/> Select All
</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"/> Opt 1 
</li>
<li> <input type="checkbox"/> Opt 2
</li>
```

...

```
function checkAll(e) {
   console.log(e)
   var checked = $(e.srcElement)[0].checked;
   console.log(checked)

   if (checked) {           
       $(this).parents("li").nextAll().foreach(function(){
          $(this).find("input").prop("checked",true);
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Paste Some of your html to understand.

You are making it complex. You just need to check all checkboxes of first li like

```
$(this).find("li:first-of-type").find("input").change(function(){

   // select your all checkbox CLASS or ID here 
    $(this).find("li:first-of-type").nextAll().foreach(function(){
        $(this).find("input").prop("checked",true);
    });

});
```